# Finding the center of a line using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, line, linestring, turf, center

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/ericg_off/pen/zYMddde)

[OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org) had a getCentroid function that would provide the line center, but that function went away at some point.

What is working is getting the center of the extent of the line:

```
ol.extent.getCenter(line.getExtent());
```

However, I am not sure why this is working. Is it because I am using the `EPSG:4326` projection?

What I thought should work using [turf](https://turfjs.org) is:

```
const bearing = turf.rhumbBearing(a, b);
const distanceToCenter = turf.rhumbDistance(a, b, { units: "degrees" }) / 2.0;
const turfCenterCoordinate = turf.getCoord(
  turf.rhumbDestination(a, distanceToCenter, bearing, { units: "degrees" })
);
```

However, it is not returning a point that falls on the drawn line center. Why does this not work?

Comment: A Rhumb line will not appear to be straight in EPSG:4326 unless it follows a parallel or meridian as the x and y scales of the projection are not equal, and that ratio differs with latitude.

Comment: Are you talking about line with only two points?

Comment: @TomazicM yes, I am.

Comment: @Mike If not turf, is there an alternative library that would consider the line between the two points to be straight?

Comment: For any LineString in OpenLayers you can use `line.getCoordinateAt(0.5)` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_LineString-LineString.html#getCoordinateAt